# Customize window snapping on Ubuntu 16.04 with gnome-shell on two screens

Tags: 16.04, multiple-monitors, gnome-shell

I have bought a second screen and am now facing the following inconvenience:

When you move a window towards the edge of a screen, it gets maximized across half the screen. If you have just one screen, you click and hold the window title bar, and just jerk the mouse cursor towards the left or right, where it ends up on the edge of the screen. Perfect.

Now with two screens, if you want the window to be maximized across the right half of the left screen, you need to drag the window towards the edge of the screen and there is a small margin where you need to hover with your mouse cursor and it will maximize. My question is:

Is this margin customizable? Aka: Can I make it wider so this becomes less of a fine-tuning act?

System is Ubuntu 16.04 with gnome-shell 3.18.5.

Thanks for any help!

Cheers, Matthias

Comment: Can you use the keyboard shortcuts to accomplish this (until someone answers your question) meta+left/right should cause the current window to be maximized on the left/right side of the screen.

Comment: Yes, this is the way I am doing it at the moment. It would just be nice to have a solution which does not require the hand to go from the mouse to the keyboard and back.